# Can I get an IK constraint w/ stretch to only scale bones on their Y axes?

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints

I have a short IK chain with an IK constraint with stretch enabled.  The bones in the chain each have their Inverse Kinematics Stretch set to 0.001.  Here's a simple demo setup...

[image: Simple IK setup w/ a 3 bone chain and a target bone]

Moving the Control bone around within reach of the IK chain seems to work fine.  E.g.

[image: IK constraint doing its job]

But when I cause the stretch to take effect by moving the target out of reach of the IK chain, the chain stretches and scales in all 3 dimensions causing the mesh to expand.  Note the size of the mesh and IK chain bones relative to the target as compared with the other images.

[image: Entire object inflates instead of just stretching]

Is there some way to only have this stretch along the Y axes of the bones?  I.e. I want the bones and mesh to elongate but not swell.  I have tried various other settings, including locking X and Z scaling on the bones.

You can grab a .blend file of the sample setup at http://readyposition.com/Blender/IKStretchExperiment.blend

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IK stretch bones do stretch in all 3 axes and can't behave like you want.
The solution and common method is to

- duplicate all the bones in the chain (except the control) and un-parent them from each other
- for each bone_copy set *Copy Location* and *Copy Rotation* constraints targeting the original bone
- for each bone_copy set *Stretch To* constraint targeting the next bone in the chain. This constraint should have *Volume* set to *XZ* to maintain reality or to *None* if you only want to stretch in Y axis
- bind the mesh to the copied bones

Comment: Thanks.  I came up with that solution as well.  I was just hoping to simplify.  And this does it.